# Query on Invalid Character Literals in Java

Tags: java

I learnt that, character literals in below four lines are invalid.

```
char ch1 = '\u000a'; //Line feed
char ch2 = '\u000d'; //Carriage return
char ch3 = '\u0027'; // ' character
char ch4 = '\u005C'; // \ character
```

My question:

I would like to understand, Why these character literals are invalid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A line feed means moving one line forward. The code is \n. A carriage return means moving the cursor to the beginning of the line. The code is \r.

Unicode escapes are pre-processed before the compiler is run. Therefore, if you put \u000A in a String literal like this:

```
char ch1 = ''; //Line feed  
//will be compiled as 
char ch1 = '
';

char ch2 = '\u000d'; //Carriage return
//will be compiled as
'char ch2= ';

char ch3 = '''; // ' character
//will be compiled as 
char ch3=''';

char ch4 = '\u005C'; // \ character
//will be compiled as
char ch4='\';
```

so these all are wrong at compile time

Answer (score 6):

It is not that they are invalid, what really happens is that the source parser converts all the `\uXXXX` ocurrences before starting to parse the lexical tokens of the code; so, for instance, if you have something like `char ch1='\u000a'; //Line feed` the parser will convert yor source code to something like this:

```
char ch1 = '
'; //Line feed
```

which is a syntax error.

Just as an exercise, do this:

```
System.out.println("Hola mundo\u0022);
```

and it will compile, because  `\u0022` is double quote, so the above code is converted to this:

```
System.out.println("Hola mundo");
```

Comment: @overexchange indeed, have a look at the section 3.2 of the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html) for more details

Comment: As per 3.2 JLS, Parsing is done in 3 phases, In first phase, [char ch='\u00A5';] will become [char ch = '¥';] ?

Comment: @overexchange granted, not exactly 2 times but more than once, and the \uXXXX are treated first anyway. And yes, your source `char ch='\u00A5';` will become `char ch = '¥';`

Answer (score 1):

Because such literals are actually translated before compile time (whether that be character literals or in strings); as such, the first example gives:

```
char ch1 = '
';
```

which is invalid syntax.

This is not a problem within strings though. You can write:

```
String s = "\u000a";
```

since:

```
String s = "
";
```

*is* valid syntax.

Comment: so before compile time this line [char ch='\u00A5';] will become [char ch = '¥';] ?

Comment: @fge Try to compile that (`String s = "\u000a";`), it won't